# sshfs login problem on android - invalid argument

Tags: sshfs

I am login into android phone as usual, but facing problem as below:
Try 1: (failed)

```
$ sshfs -p 8022 u0_a402@192.168.43.189:/storage ~/sshfs-mount2 -o IdentityFile=~/.ssh/termux-rsa  
sshfs: invalid argument `u0_a402@192.168.43.189:/storage'
```

Try 2: (failed)

```
$ sshfs -p 8022 u0_a402@192.168.43.189 ~/sshfs-mount -o IdentityFile=~/.ssh/termux-rsa 
sshfs: invalid argument `u0_a402@192.168.43.189'
```

Try 3: (failed)

```
$ sshfs -p 8022 192.168.43.189 ~/sshfs-mount -o IdentityFile=~/.ssh/termux-rsa   
sshfs: invalid argument `192.168.43.189'
```

Try4:  (ssh success)

```
ssh -p 8022 192.168.43.189 -o IdentityFile=~/.ssh/termux-rsa 

Welcome to Termux!

Docs:       https://termux.dev/docs
Donate:     https://termux.dev/donate
Community:  https://termux.dev/community
.....
```

What's the problem with sshfs login ?  I want to mount my phone on a folder on manjaro laptop.
This sshfs used to work, but somehow when i used phone hotspot to connect, it have this problem.

Comment: It seems to be correct the syntax. Maybe you have and alias. What is the output of `type -a sshfs`?

Comment: $ type -a sshfs
sshfs is an alias for sshfs -p 8022 u0_a402@192.168.43.1:/ ~/sshfs-mount -o IdentityFile=~/.ssh/termux-rsa

Comment: That seems to be the problem, you should disable the alias, or what should work: just type `sshfs` without any arguments

Comment: Thanks.. That is really the problem. After renamed the alias sshfs to sshfs1; everything works flawlessly.

Comment: I rolled back your recent edit tagging the title with "SOLVED". If you have a solution, consider adding that solution as a separate answer and accept it later. Accepting an answer will mark the question as resolved. Please see  https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I didn't solve the problem by myself, it is Edgar Magallon who found the solution for me.. So i can't take credit for it.

Comment: @andrew_ysk I will post as an answer so you can mark as accepted :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command did not work because `sshfs` had an alias for `sshfs -p 8022 u0_a402@192.168.43.1:/ ~/sshfs-mount -o IdentityFile=~/.ssh/termux-rsa` thus when you try to run your command this fails.

You can solve the problem by using:

1. Unalias your command in your shell file (e.g. if it's bash then it'd be `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases` perhaps)
2. Simply run the command `sshfs` without arguments. But given that the alias use `u0_a402@192.168.43.1:/` and you use `u0_a402@192.168.43.189:/storage` then this should not be useful.
3. Prefix a `\` to your command to avoid your shell uses the alias:

```bash
\sshfs -p 8022 u0_a402@192.168.43.189:/storage ~/sshfs-mount2 -o IdentityFile=~/.ssh/termux-rsa
```